# Saying Yizkor before its time

Tags: halacha, yizkor

Due to the situation with the Coronavirus, there are people that are doing a Yizkor service online before Yom TOV I.e. Tuesday 14th although Yizkor would normally be recited on last day of Yom Tov.

My question is can Yizkor be said before its normal time?

Comment: Is there a time one can't say yizkor? I can't think of one.

Comment: I dont know why one would resort to that since one can say yizkor on yom tov itself without minyan . Rav Schachter addresses this in his teshuvos

Comment: @sam probably for people who need guidance for how to say it